# Change iOS simulator iCloud account

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to debug a CloudKit issue which means I need to see the data being saved to iCloud in the CloudKit dashboard. I have two iCloud accounts, one which is for my personal email address, and the other for my work address and which I use for iOS development. The iOS simulator seemed to pick up the iCloud account from the Mac, so the entries being saved by the app were not visible in the CloudKit dashboard. I tried logging the Mac out of my personal iCloud account, logging in to the work account, restarting the computer, resetting the content and settings of the simulator, cleaning and rebuilding the app, but it still shows all of the data I entered while on the personal iCloud account. How can I configure Xcode or the simulator to log in to a different iCloud account?

Comment: Ok now this is just weird. I've logged in to a brand new user account, logged in to the desired iCloud account, and launched the app from Xcode. It still shows the data I entered previously, under a different Mac user and on a different iCloud account :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFS... I'm an idiot. I was using the public database